# Deleting all rows where value in a particular cell is not equal to 0 or N/A

Tags: vba, excel

I've applied a formula to a particular cell, a count if, to ensure it shows number as 0 the first time the number appears, and 1 and 2 etc going forward.

Now i need help in macro to delete all the times the number is not 0 or N/A (places where it is text, that should not be deleted). I tried recording a macro and slightly change my credentials, but it is not working at all. Please help. It's in a bad shape right now considering all the iterations that i tried to make.

```
raw.Range("D3:D" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(OR(AND(A1="""",A2=""""),AND(A1="""",A4<>"""")),""N/A"",COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A3))"
    Rows("A:D" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$E" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria:<>("0"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Rows("1830:1830").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$E$3585").AutoFilter Field:=4
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete the first four cells of each row that's duplicated. It leaves the first row that had the duplicate value in Column A in place.  Any duplicate text values are also left alone.

```
Sub deleteDuplicates()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        iRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        While iRow > 0
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(iRow, 1)), .Cells(iRow, 1)) > 1 _
                And Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(.Cells(iRow, 1)) Then
                .Range(.Cells(iRow, 1), .Cells(iRow, 4)).Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
            iRow = iRow - 1
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```